# React/JS toStringLocale returning incorrect time when server in a different time zone to user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, timezone

I've encountered a strange problem that I can't debug (or even replicate), however it's been reported by several users.

My app is built in React and is used by travel agents and displays the times of flights. However some users have experienced incorrect flight times being shown in the front end - usually the same offset between the client and their server. I've done some testing and the front end is receiving the time correctly from the backend. This problem happens when a user is located in one time zone, but their internet traffic is routed through another time zone. For example a client is located in Sydney, but their head office is Brisbane and hence all their internet traffic routed through the Brisbane office.

A simplified version of the code is below

```
componentDidMount=()=>{
    //api request to server to fetch flight times
    api.getFlightTimes();
    .then(res=>{
    //the below displays the correct flight time from the server in the format "2019-10-26 20:50"
        console.log(res.flightTime);
        const depTimeFormatted = res.flightTime.toLocaleString(en_GB, {
            hour: "numeric",
            minute: "2-digit",
            hour12: false
        });
    })
    //this is where the problem happens. The below Displays 19:50 for certain users
    console.log(depTimeFormatted);
}
```

Like I said this only happens when the users internet traffic is routed through a server not in their time zone, so I'm having real trouble replicating the issue!

Comment: why u don't use moment ?

Comment: to replicate the issue you can use proxy server at your end.

Comment: @walidsahli—how will moment.js fix an issue that the OP can't even define?

Comment: How is "2019-10-26 20:50" converted to a Date? On 26 October Sydney will be UTC+11, Brisbane will be UTC+10 so 20:50 in Sydney is 19:50 in Brisbane.

Comment: @dtwoo -  Please edit your question to make it [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also, note that `String.toLocaleString` is just the same as `String.toString`, which is just the original string.  Thus `res.FlightTime` would have to be a `Date` object for any of the parameters you're passing to do anything at all, but it's clearly not, according to your comment about how it formats.